# PHP、PDOでINSERTできない。

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHPでサインインAPIを作成したのですが、以下のコードに書かれている箇所でmysqlへのインサートが失敗してしまいます。いろいろ試してみたのですが、どこが間違っているのかわかりません。
いろいろ試した結果以下のことがわかりました。

- `lastInsertId()`は正しく呼ばれていてidを取得出来ている。
- 1つ前のINSERTは成功している。
- テーブル名、カラム名は正しい。
- エラーは出ない。

どなたか、どこが間違っているのかわかりますか?

**ソースコード**

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("X-Content-Type-Option: nosniff");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'session_util.php';

$pdo = initDB();
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
  case 'POST':
    $in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $error = '';
    if(isset($in['mail_address'])&&isset($in['password'])&&isset($in['username'])){
      if(!checkEmail($pdo, $in['mail_address'])){
        $error = "メールアドレスが登録済みです。";
        header("HTTP/1.0 402 Unauthexed");
        sendError($error);
      }else{
        $st = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user (mail_address, password, username) VALUES (:mail_address, :password, :username)");
        $st->bindParam(':mail_address', $in['mail_address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $hashedPassword = makeHash($in['password']);
        $st->bindParam(':password', $hashedPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindParam(':username', $in['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($st->execute()){
          $userId = $pdo->lastInsertId('id');
          $st2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO user_profile (user_id, username) VALUES (:user_id, :username)");
          $st2->bindValue(":user_id", $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $st2->bindParam(":username", $in['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          //このif文で失敗する。
          if($st2->execute()){
            header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            onSuccess($pdo, $in['mail_address'], $userId);
          }else{
            $error="Un known error.";
            sendError($error);
          }
        }else{
          $error = "server error";
          header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
          sendError($error);
        }
      }
    }else{
      $error = "メールアドレスとパスワードを入力してください。";
      header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
      sendError($error);
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: エラーが出ないということですが、そもそもエラーが出るように設定していますか？ http://php.net/manual/ja/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: 設定していますが、でませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。原因はuser_profileテーブルのidがauto_incrementになっていませんでした。
お騒がせしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

SQL文がエラーになっていそうなので

```
      //このif文で失敗する。
      if($st2->execute()){
        header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        onSuccess($pdo, $in['mail_address'], $userId);
      }else{
        $error="Un known error.";
        sendError($error);
      }
```

のelse節の中で

```
        $st2->errorInfo();
```

によって実際のエラー原因を調べてみたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: `sendError`の引数で`$st2->errorInfo()`をブラウザがわに送ってみたところ以下のレスポンスがありました。
`["00000",null,null]`

Answer (score -1):

エラーの原因はわかり易くなるために毎度以下のlogファイルを見たほうがいいと思います。

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_file%';
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**すみません、日本語は少しだけしゃべれます。